# How to tell a recruiter that I would be interested in his offer in the future?

Tags: job-offer, new-job, recruitment, job-change

Let me begin by telling my current scenario. I’m a 2021 graduate whose job search was hit by the pandemic. I had one job offer that was revoked but fortunately I got another offer at a startup after extensive job hunt. Though the offer wasn’t very much to my liking, I didn’t have much to choose from.

It has been one month since my joining and I have been contacted by three recruiter from big companies already. I have politely declined them the ground that I have just joined and it wouldn’t be good to look for another job. It’s not like I don’t want to join those companies but I feel guilty in responding to the recruiters only a month after joining even though I feel I would be looking to move on from my current company in future. I wanted to know how to respond to any recruiters in the future to let them know that although, I might not be interested in joining now, I might be open in the future. Also I wanted to know whether it matters to the recruiter or not that person has just joined the company?

Comment: Just be specific.  "thanks, hit me up again in six months."

Comment: " it wouldn’t be good to look for another job. " Not true in your case. As a fresh graduate during Covid you have at least one hall pass for a short first job.  You are getting offers: Obviously your prospective employers don't care, so why would you? If you find something great, go for it. Just make sure you do due diligence on that role so can stay there comfortably for at least two years.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recruiters earn their money by recruiting people. If these people are working in their current role for 1 month or 1 decade is none of their worry.

Also recruiters, at least those who have crossed my path, are usually focused on the present: if you are not available now but only maybe interested later, you will end up in some sort of archive where they keep all their candidates who didn't earn a big red cross on their name.

You can simply tell that at the moment you are not looking for new possibilities but that you want to be informed of future ones. However, since that list I mentioned is pretty long, should you really need a new job don't rely on the recruiter to contact you, but be proactive and make the first step.